# What does "Restore Ban" means in Fail2Ban logs?

Tags: security, fail2ban

Here's output from command `sudo zgrep 'Ban' /var/log/fail2ban.log*`

```
2021-11-02 17:11:14,167 fail2ban.actions        [30809]: NOTICE  [sshd] Ban 38.91.102.38
2021-11-02 17:12:27,085 fail2ban.actions        [31041]: NOTICE  [sshd] Restore Ban 38.91.102.38
```

What does "Restore Ban" means?

Answer (score 5):

It means fail2ban is banning that IP after the service is started/restarted, and that ip was banned before, so fail2ban is restoring the state of 'ban' for that IP.

For example:

1. At 1pm, IP 1.2.3.4 is banned for 1 day
2. A few minutes later, the fail2ban service is shutdown due to a server reboot.
3. When fail2ban starts again, it goes through the database and it bans 1.2.3.4 again.

Therefore the ban is restored.